# VBscript to copy range and paste special transpose to rows at a variable location

Tags: excel, vbscript

Trying to copy a range of data into a variable location and transpose the information from columns to rows.  I keep receiving paste special method of range class failed.  Line 15 Char 1.

New to VBScript and any help would be great!

```
set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts=False
const xlDown = -4121
const xlUp = -4162
const xlPasteValues = -4163
set wb = xl.WorkBooks.open("https://Sharepoint address/SummaryKPI.xlsx")
WScript.Sleep 1000
If wb.WorkSheets("DataHistoryTurns").Range("A75536").End(xlUp).Value2 < Date Then
wb.LockServerFile
WScript.Sleep 100
wb.WorkSheets("Dashboard").Range("B2:B7").Copy
wb.WorkSheets("DataHistoryInv").Range("A75536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues,,,True
wb.WorkSheets("DataHistoryInv").Range("A75536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).value = Date
wb.WorkSheets("Dashboard").Range("E2:B8").Copy
wb.WorkSheets("DataHistoryTurns").Range("A75536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues,,,True
wb.WorkSheets("DataHistoryTurns").Range("A75536").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).value = Date
wb.Save
End If
wb.Close
xl.Application.DisplayAlerts=True
xl.Quit
```

Comment: I seem to remember this code being posted a few days ago and it was a typo on `Offset(1,0)` was `Offset(1.0)`. Seems to be the same question as well, it was closed and looks to have been deleted. So this is attempt two I'm guessing...

Comment: On line 15, it looks like you're overlapping the copy\paste. For transpose, they need to be separate regions.

Comment: @Mike67 The copy is on "Dashboard" worksheet and I am pasting to "DataHistoryInv" worksheet - no overlap on the copy/paste.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro in VBA?  That should help narrow down the issue. Also - did you try this script on a local copy of the file (not sharepoint)?

Comment: @Mike67 Already did the macro -  and then have slowly converted it to VBScript you see today.  I have not tried on a local copy of the file.  I will try during my lunch break and report back.

Comment: @Mike67 still received the same paste method error.  Troubleshooting...I may try a different method instead of copy paste but directly say cell.value = transpose(cell.value)  and see if that works